# How to write function in async mode when $rootscope.broadcast is being used in an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

I have a following function which gets called at least 10 times in a second. Every time I have around 100 records which are same except it's LastSeenTime, ReadCount. Since this is a simulator so I know the behaviour however in real time, no of records in an array may vary from 100 - 1000. They may or may not be same. I need to add all distinct records to tagStore which is being displayed in UI thereafter.

```
$scope.$on('getReadTags', function (event, tags) {

        if (($scope.tagStore == null || $scope.tagStore.length == 0) && tags.length != 0) {
            $scope.tagStore = tags;
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                var notFound = true;

                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.tagStore.length; j++) {
                    if (tags[i].TagID == $scope.tagStore[j].TagID) {
                        $scope.tagStore[j].ReadCount += tags[i].ReadCount;
                        $scope.tagStore[j].LastSeenTime = tags[i].LastSeenTime;
                        $scope.tagStore[j].DiscoveryTime = tags[i].DiscoveryTime;
                        notFound = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!notFound) {
                    $scope.tagStore.push(tags[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

When I runs this code, my browser gets stuck. I also noticed that my CPU, RAM utilization is shooting very high. What I need is that this method should be called only after first method has completed it's execution.

Comment: Javascript is single thread execution, the code is running in sequence only, just that you are making so many request the tight loop causes the CPU spikes.

Comment: Is there a way then, i can cut down this work load depending upon if my loop has been finished. Then only broadcast next message again?

Comment: I think method is being called multiple times even before my first loop could complete. Because I could see my array is growing, otherwise it should have had just 100 records. Right now I see it going over 2000 before I kills the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking multiple digest cycles one after the other, and this usually makes to CPU and memory consumption jump to the sky, and hang the browser.

Use [`$applyAsync`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) instead of `$scope.$apply();` to collect multiple `$apply` into one $digest cycle. As you can see in the documentation (bold area):

> $applyAsync([exp]); Schedule the invocation of $apply to occur at a
>   later time. The actual time difference varies across browsers, but is
>   typically around ~10 milliseconds.
>
> **This can be used to queue up multiple expressions which need to be**
>   **evaluated in the same digest.**

This loop `for (var j = 0; j < $scope.tagStore.length; j++) {` is redundant, as it iterates the whole list of tags, for every tag inserted, and half of it on average for every tag updated. Do this instead:

```
var tagsMap;

$scope.$on('getReadTags', function (event, tags) {  
    if (($scope.tagStore == null || $scope.tagStore.length == 0) && tags.length != 0) {
        $scope.tagStore = tags;
        tagsMap = tags.reduce(function(obj, item) {
            obj[item.TagID] = item; // create a map of all tags
        }, {});
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            if(tagsMap[tags[i].TagID]) { // if tag exists in the map, update the tag
                tagsMap[tags[i].TagID].ReadCount += tags[i].ReadCount;
                tagsMap[tags[i].TagID].LastSeenTime = tags[i].LastSeenTime;
                tagsMap[tags[i].TagID].DiscoveryTime = tags[i].DiscoveryTime;
            } else { // if tag doesn't exist, push it into the scope, and add it to the tagsMap
                $scope.tagStore.push(tags[i]);
                tagsMap[tags[i].TagID] = tags[i];
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.$applyAsync();
});
```

Comment: Do I need to move all my code inside $appyAsync method?

Comment: No (same as apply), but it's preferable if you want angular error handling.

Comment: This worked partially, now my browser is not hanging however CPU/RAM utilization is still rising.

Comment: You have a loop inside a loop to check if tag needs insertion or update. See edit.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know about reduce method. Concept looks good. i will test it during my evening.